# Create an array of ids with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am trying to create an array of ids so that I can query if a certain id is associated with an object. Here is my method but it isnt adding id's to the array.

```
class Report
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_and_belongs_to_many :reportapprovals, class_name: "Reportapproval", inverse_of: :report

  def bind_reportapproval
    @reportapprovals = Reportapproval.where(tenant_id: self.tenant_id).all

    if @reportapprovals.present? && @reportapprovals.any? { |ra| ra.tenant_approved == true }
      @reportapprovals.each do |ra|
        self.reportapproval_ids = ra.id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is suppose to add an array of reportapproval_ids to the report object.

Comment: Well, you set the value to each id then continually overwrite it.

Comment: ok, how do i fix that add them to an array with <<? Also when I look at it in console there are NO id's?

Comment: In the `if` statement you've got this: `@reportapprovals.any? { |tenant_approved| tenant_approved == true}` which is going to iterate through each `reportapproval` and check if it is equal to `true`, but it won't ever be since it will be an instance of a Mongoid record. Did you maybe mean something like this? `@reportapprovals.any? { |ra| ra.tenant_approved == true}`

Comment: thanks for that @neuronaut!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails actually has a method for that:

```
if @reportapprovals.present? && @reportapprovals.any? { |tenant_approved| tenant_approved }
  self.reportapproval_ids = @reportapprovals.ids
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the value of the array equal to ONE ID. Try this:

```
if true # use correct conditional statement
  self.reportapproval_ids = @reportapprovals.pluck(:id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the answer but the other is cleaner.